# How do I install an archived CRAN package

Tags: r

I am trying to use the allanvar package which is documented on this [rdocumentation page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/allanvar/versions/1.1/topics/allanvar) and this [rdrr.io cran page](https://rdrr.io/cran/allanvar/man/allanvar-package.html). When I attempt to load it I get the following

```
    > install.packages("allanvar")
Error: package 'allanvar' is not available
```

Am I doing something wrong, or has it been yanked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see if a package has been archived, you can go to its CRAN page. In this case, it is https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/allanvar , but it's the same url pattern for other packages. Just put the package name after the last forward slash.

You will see on this page that it has been archived since 2020. To get the last stable CRAN version (which passed all CRAN checks with R version 4.0.2), you can do:

```r
devtools::install_version('allanvar', version = '1.1')
```

Answer (score 2):

This package is archived. This could be due to some minuscule thing that would be resolved soon, see [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/allanvar/index.html).

In the meantime, I'd install this using the GitHub repo:

```r
remotes::install_github("jhidalgocarrio/allanvar")
```

Comment: I found it by searching on google. There are enough breadcrumbs here to serve anyone that experience the same issue in the future.